# Zend Plugin not working in godaddy host account

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a Zend based application and its running on my localhost(my computer), but its not running on my shared hosting account.

Normal applications (without any Zend plugins) is working well on my account but when I try to register a Zend plugin in applicaton.ini file I'm getting 500 (Internal server error)

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Addons"
resources.frontController.plugins.HeaderFormat = "Addons_HeaderFormat"
resources.frontController.plugins.ArchiveTagMenu = "Addons_ArchiveTagMenu"
```

Comment: I would sign into your hosting account and view the error logs to see what is generating the 500 error.  Can you paste in what the error looks says?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your browser to see Detailed Errors instead of error 500.  Then you'll know where the problem is and try to fix it.